# Библиотеки для работы с obj файлами в с++

Tags: c++, поиск-библиотек, obj

Сейчас я работаю над трассировкой лучей на С++. Мне нужно рендерить обьект, который описан в obj файле. Есть ли библиотеки для работы с такими файлами или для работы с геометрией?

Comment: openGL  смотрели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предлагаю обратить внимание на [Intel Embree](https://www.embree.org/). Библиотека бесплатная, с открытым C++ кодом, распространяемым по Apache лицензии.

В частности, обратите внимание [на базовые туториалы](https://www.embree.org/tutorials.html), в частности напрямую направленные на обучение "работе" с obj файлами:

- Viewer ([также на Гитхабе](https://github.com/embree/embree/tree/master/tutorials/viewer))
- Path Tracer ([также на Гитхабе](https://github.com/embree/embree/tree/master/tutorials/pathtracer))

Попробовать воспользоваться этой библиотекой довольно удобно так как можно попробовать взять базовый функционал и разрабатывать свой модульно, а также, например, сравнивать свои алгоритмы для трассировки лучей с уже предоставленными Intel Embree. Также, существует довольно [богатая экосистема проектов](https://www.embree.org/related.html), включающая Intel OSPray (визуализация), многочисленные рендеры разной направленности и куча научной литературы.

Также на Гитхабе:

- [основной репозиторий](https://github.com/embree/embree)
- [каталог побочных репозиториев с документацией, примерами и т.д.](https://github.com/embree)